# how to fetch sorted data use namequery

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

for fetching sorted value from db using hibernate, I use this NamedQuery:

```
@NamedQuery(
    name = "searchnearestdesc",
    query = "select t FROM Result t WHERE t.indec=:e"
        + "t.var<=:f ORDER BY var DESC"
    )
```

But, I get exception, 
what is my error?

Comment: What exception do you get? And what do you want that query to do for you? I can't understand why you are doing this: - `"t.var=l<=:f"`?

Comment: I want to to fetch value smaller than f

Comment: And what is `f`? Also post your stacktrace. What exceptions are you getting?

Comment: a value entered by user, e.g. 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a AND between your clauses, also don't forget the trailing space when concatening strings ;)

```
@NamedQuery(
name = "searchnearestdesc",
query = "select t FROM Result t WHERE t.indec=:e AND "
    + "t.var<=:f ORDER BY var DESC"
)
```

Comment: I use AND , but I have exception yet

Comment: @saeedarash.. Unless you show us what exception you get, we can't help.

Comment: I am trying to find my exception

Comment: org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known:searchnearestas

Comment: You declare a query named `searchnearestdesc` and you seem to be calling `searchnearestas`

Comment: @saeedarash.. Don't forget to accept this answer. Click the arrow besides the answer to mark it as accepted.